# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer from CIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, ciimage

I'm making a camera app with filters in it. I can get filtered CIImage from the filter. But how can i display the filtered image directly to the preview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OpenGL view. In every step you need to get frame from camera output, add filter and render it to screen.
You can find some example [here](https://github.com/gdavis/iOS-CoreImage-Camera/tree/master/CICamera).